# What's the adjective for a person who cares much?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

For example, I want to say to my mum:

> Oh, I could cook something myself. It's better for you just go in the room and rest after this crazy day you had. Mum... thank you for all, you're so ____. (you care about me so much)

What would be a word that has a positive connotation?

Comment: Idiomatically, we don't say someone "cares much".  We could say that someone "cares a lot" or that someone "doesn't care much", but not "cares much".  I don't know why, but that's just the way it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjective: my parents are very **caring** people.

You are so caring. [not usually used with friends like that]. It is a very strong phrase in fact. So, you might say your parents are caring people and would probably say: **Oh Mum, you care about me so much. [or: You care about me so much]** And not: Oh Mum, you are **so caring**. **Unless you mean how your mother is in relation to others, like the poor etc.** to be caring = to be generous and nice to others.

Verb: My mother cares a lot about me. 
My cousin doesn't care a lot [or much] about me.

As has been pointed out, a lot is used in the declarative.

much and not much can be used in the negative and interrogative:

- Do you care a lot about him? Do you care much about him?
- They don't care much about us. They don't care a lot about us.
- Do they care about you? Answer: Not much, not a lot.
- I really care a lot about my dog.

Word of advice: to care about a person means to like or even to love. The more formal term is: to care **for** a person (like or love) but it also means: to take care of, as in: My mothers cares for my disabled aunt.

As an additional word of advice: much, many in most declarative sentences in spoken English becomes a lot of or lots of rather than much or many. In the negative and interrogative, many or much is used but a lot and lots of can also be used. (This is just a general idea here. Not every detail of usage. And I am not distinguishing here between adverbs and adjectives, for the record).

Answer (score 0):

There are many alternatives that can be used to finish this sentence. For example:

> you're so kind to me.
>
> you're so compassionate at times like this.
>
> you're so solicitous of my needs.
>
> you're so caring when I really need it.

Comment: thank you so much, but I was looking for the adjective to describe my mum's kindness and to emphasize that it's in her nature to take care. like, "my mum is very ___" (___ - the adjective I'm trying to find out :))

Comment: Then **caring**  would be your choice. "My mum is very caring"

Comment: @Mary Zlyden There are terms such as philanthropic, kind-hearted, altruistic, charitable, etc., but I think they are terms used to describe kind strangers; not your own mum. For your mum, I would recommend caring, attentive, devoted, doting, or protective.